# Forefront TMG - URL Overrides - how long does it take for them to come into play?

Tags: isa-server, microsoft-forefront, microsoft-ftmg, microsoft-ftmg-2010

Adding a URL to a category seems seems to take an age, somewhere along the lines of 3 to 4 hours.

Is this normal behaviour?

Could someone tell me what is the default length of time that it takes for an overriden URL to take effect?

Also, is there an option to decrease the amount of time it takes?

Many thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

I remembered it being near-instant (standard two minute rule applies for any ISA or TMG operation - once the two cpu spikes have subsided, it's usually ready to go).

I browsed to microsoft.com, and noted that it was categorized as "Technical Information". I then added a URL category override, to tell it it was "Alcohol" related.

That took effect pretty-well instantly, as did alcoholizing *.technet.microsoft.com/* .

There could be a number of things going on; if you're using Enterprise Edition and defining overrides at that level, you might have a really long poll interval set for the EMS.

It's also possible that the local cache entry for the microsoft sites is really short, and the site you're overriding has a longer cache duration; I don't know how to look at these, or flush them.